# MySQL/Rails - Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' to database 'simple_cms_development'):

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to both MySQL and Rails. I'm going through a course on Lynda (Ruby on Rails 5) and I ran into a hiccup. After creating a database it's having me start up MySQL and Puma. I attempt to access localhost:3000 however I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' to database 'simple_cms_development'):
```

It seems like everything is working properly, both MySQL and Puma start:

```
Johns-MBP:simple_cms johnerickson$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
SUCCESS!
Johns-MBP:simple_cms johnerickson$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
* List item
```

Below is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: rails_user
  password: ***The password works***
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_development
```

I looked through Stack Overflow and see others have had similar issues, however it seemed to be a password issue, which I'm not having. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular user does not have enough rights to access the DB. Try after running following commands in mysql prompt. You may have to log as root or some other admin user in order to run this.

```
grant all on simple_cms_development.* to 'rails_user'@'localhost' identified by '<password>';
flush privileges;
```

Comment: Thank you Aruna. I did something similar to the code you listed above previously minus the 'flush privileges;'. I started the video series from the beginning and I got it to work. Not exactly sure what I did different, but I do appreciate your feedback. It goes a long way and so that I thank you!